Static files path generated incorrectly in Django project
Description:
In my Django project, the static files path is generated incorrectly, appending the current page URL before the static URL. For example, when I'm on the about page, the path becomes http://127.0.0.1:8000/about/static/images/bg/17.jpg instead of http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/images/bg/17.jpg. This causes issues with serving static files. How can I debug and fix this issue?
STATIC_URL = '/static/'   #Location of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/'), ]
MEDIA_ROOT  = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'


from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('home.urls')),

]+static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

I've checked my settings.py file and ensured that STATIC_URL = '/static/'. My static files are located in the correct directory (static/images/bg/17.jpg). I'm using the {% static %} template tag in my templates to reference static files. I've also run collectstatic after making changes to my static files.
Expected Behavior:
I expect the static files path to be generated as http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/images/bg/17.jpg regardless of the current page URL.
